# How to start apache tomcat at system start up

Tags: suse

I normally have to run the start up script for apache and tomcat manually every time my SuSE machine start by issue command `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/bin/startup.sh`.
Is there a way I can set for this script to run auto automatically every time the machine startup?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Copy the file `/etc/init.d/skeleton` and rename it to `/etc/init.d/your-service`. After that edit this file to create new scripts. the comments in this file are used by Yast to describe on which runlevels the start/stop must be.

The script will then show in YaST → System → System Services (runlevel), you can the enable it using chkconfig to create the appropriate links

```
chkconfig --set your-service on
```

you can also activate it in some runlevels using

```
chkconfig --level 35 someservice on
```

to desactivate the service you can use

chkconfig --set your-service off

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with SuSE 12 distros (including SLES12), SuSE has implemented **systemd**.

**systemd** is (disputably) meant to eventually replace **SysV init scripts** on Linux.

SuSE 12 distros continue to support both **SysV init scripts**, as well as the new **systemd**.

However, it is likely that your desire to automatically start Tomcat on each system boot has already been anticipated by SuSE; which already has a **systemd** entry in SuSE 12 distros.

Hence, on SuSE 12 distros, Tomcat automatic start can be enabled in:

```
YaST->System->Services(Manager)->Tomcat
```

[image: YaST Tomcat Enable (Automatic Start)]

Click the **Enable/Disable** button to enable or disable automatic startup.

Also, you might find the following command-line item of value:

```
systemctl status tomcat
systemctl start tomcat
systemctl stop tomcat
```

(More commands can be found in **man systemctl**.)